# Adding Row Version to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

I have a table in a database with three columns: ID, Key and Value.  Everytime I update the record, I have a trigger that sends these updates to another table and creates a new record in it, who's schema is this:

```
RowID (new ID field for this table, identity(1,1) column)
ID (from source table)
Key (from source table)
Value (from source table)
Version (integer)
```

So anytime the first table record's changed, it creates a new record in the second with the table everytime.

For every record with a matching ID, I want to add a unique incremental version number.  If a record with ID of 1 is entered into this table 5 times, those records should have version numbers of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.  Is the way to accomplish this through a subquery for existing version numbers, or setting up a partition, or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases I am storing version numbers, and using referential integrity to make sure version numbers begin with 1 and have no gaps. Because I use constraints, I am sure my solution works in high concurrency situations. I have described this approach in [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/yet-another-sql-strategy-for-versioned-data/)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add `rowversion`([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) column to your audited table and store this number in another table? It's sequential by definition, though it doesn't start with 1.

Answer (score 0):

there is a built-in feature for this that requires minimum maintenance and is very fast except it works with timestamps.

if you can work with timestamps instead of the version I highly recommend this over manual work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-2017